# Put input text and submit button same line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a search box and search submission button, I try several way to make the button and text box in same line, but doesn't work. Here is my code.

```
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={submitHandler} inline>
      <Form.Control
        type='text'
        name='q'
        onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
        placeholder='Serach product'
        className='mr-sm-2 ml-sm-5'
      ></Form.Control>
      <Button type='submit' variant='btn btn-success' className='p-2'>
          search
      </Button>
    </Form>
  )
```

[What I expect is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAh0g.png)

[But what I have is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV0T3.png)

Reactjs version is ^17.0.1 in my package.jason file, but when I use `npm info react` in cmd it shows me react@18.1.0

Thanks the answer from Mr.Gandhi https://stackoverflow.com/a/72385731/19202374

Comment: What code is making the "What I expect is" image?  Why don't you just use that code, or is this a problem with updating react?

Comment: @MichaelM. I don't have that code since the image of what I expect is edited from what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Change the input and/or the button to be display: inline in the css
Or you can just put display flex on the parent container of the input and button.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your form elements in a div and give a className (ex: flex-container).

```
return (
    <Form onSubmit={submitHandler} inline>
      <div className="flex-container">
                <Form.Control
                    type='text'
                    name='q'
                    onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder='Serach product'
                    className='mr-sm-2 ml-sm-5'
                ></Form.Control>
                <Button type='submit' variant='btn btn-success' className='p-2'>
                        search
                </Button>
        </div>
    </Form>
  )
```

After that add below css

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
```